# Invalid indexing or function definition. Indexing must follow MATLAB indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

I wrote this in matlab :

```
syms w
Xpointfiveprime=0.5;
deltafunction= -1.9786*w^10 + 8.2992*w^9 -16.263*w^8 + 20.261*w^7 -18.484*w^6 + 13.282*w^5 -7.0156*w^4 + 2.211*w^3 +0.78186*w^2 -0.94934*w +0.85015;
deltaderivate=diff(deltafunction);
```

I got this:

> Invalid indexing or function definition. Indexing must follow MATLAB indexing. Function arguments must
>   be symbolic variables, and function body must be sym expression.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The code you provided should work fine. There is no indexing anywhere. Did you perhaps define a variable `diff` earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Matlab help page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html), your code should look like this:

```
syms f(w)
Xpointfiveprime=0.5;
f(w)= -1.9786*w^10 + 8.2992*w^9 -16.263*w^8 + 20.261*w^7 -18.484*w^6 + 13.282*w^5 -7.0156*w^4 + 2.211*w^3 +0.78186*w^2 -0.94934*w +0.85015;
deltaderivate=diff(f,w);
```

Should work! I think the problem is that deltaderivate is not seen as symbolic variable by Matlab.

Cheers

Comment: it works now...thank guys